# SQL query failure in ASP.NET Web API on wake from sleep

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

We are experiencing an edge-case error with ASP.NET Web Api 2 and MSSQL. The situation is this:

1. An external process is storing a complex token in a database record
   along with a simpler token that identifies the record.
2. The external process then redirects the user to an endpoint in our API passing the simple token in the url.
3. The API uses the simple token to look up the database and retrieve the complex token
4. The user is then redirected to another url with the complex token injected into the window object of the response.

Here is the problem:

Two simultaneous requests, from different users, come in to retrieve complex tokens the server. The first request fails. The second request gets served the complex token that is associated with the first request.

*This only occurs when the Windows Server is waking from sleep.*

At all other times the users send in their simple token and receive back the correct complex token.

Can anybody shed any light on what is causing the problem and how to fix?

A simplified version of the code that is associated with this case is here:

```
// The Controller action that receives the simple Token
public ActionResult GetToken(string simpleToken)
{
    ApiOutput.UserToken.Token = QueryToken(simpleToken);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

// The method that retrieves the complex token from the database
public static string QueryToken(string simpleToken)
{
    using (var _wdb = new AppDbContext())
    {
        var data = _wdb.TokenData.FirstOrDefault(d => d.SimpleToken == simpleToken);

        return data.ComplexToken;
    }
}

// Controller Index action
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}



<!-- The Index view where the complex token is returned -->
@{ Layout = null; }
@using myApp.Models
@model ApiOutput.UserToken

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
        <script>
            window.dbtoken = "@ApiOutput.UserToken.Token";
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sounds like a race condition, but impossible to say from what little code you posted.

Comment: Thanks for that. You might be right and that gives me an avenue to investigate and correct for